# Access higher level component (parent) properties from subsubcomponents (children of children)

Tags: vue.js

I am working on something which requires access to a property injected at the top level of a VueJS application. I can access the property by using:

```
this.$parent.$attrs.propertyname
```

This works nicely however, I am now wanting to be able to access the same item from a further subcomponent which works the same as above with an additional $parent call. Is there a way I can call this item at the top level in another way?

I have looked at $root and tested using Vue $vm console calls in the browser but doesnt work so far. I suspect theres a really easy way of doing this but I can't find it at the moment.

I have tried:

- adding a return method from top level and calling it
- $root
- setting a prototype outside the vue application at the top level: Vue.prototype.$varname = '' and then attempting to assign on created() to this.$varname = this.mypropertyname

I suspect I am close somewhere or there is something I have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did plenty of fiddling and I have my answer.

So basically, my application passes data into the app from Laravel at the  tag level. I have an overall template file for the app which is where I now set the data with a setter to root.

I will explain with some code:

Laravel:

```
<v-app token="abcdefg">
    <template></template>
</v-app>
```

Thats the declaration of data passed into the app

On template.vue:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: "template",
    created() {
        this.$root.setToken(this.$parent.$attrs.token);
    }
  }
</script>
```

We access the data and use the setter placed on app.js (root) to assign the data to an accessible $root location

app.js code:

```
const app = new Vue({
  data() {
      return {token: ''}
  },

  moment,vuetify,
  router, store,

  el: '#app',
  methods: {
      setToken(token)
      {
          this.token = token;
      },
      getToken()
      {
          return this.token;
      }
  }
});
```

A getter and setter available for the whole app to access. I may restrict access to the setter function later on but for now I am happy it works. Suggestions on restricting this will be nice.

Its now accessible via: this.$root.getToken()